# How to set grub command for other distros on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub2, grub

I am currently running Ubuntu and Fedora on the same system.  I am using the instance of grub which came with ubuntu to select which one to use when I boot. I need to add `rdblacklist=nouveau` to the command line for Fedora or else it will not load my nvidia driver.  The issue I am having is that if I want to run an update-grub in Ubuntu it will erase whatever I have added to the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, which makes sense since it is reconfiguring that file.  I know I can change my Ubuntu boot command by editing /etc/default/grub but how can I add parameters for fedora to this file?

Comment: My personal recommendation is just to handle `grub.cfg` manually, maybe using Ubuntu's output as a starting point if you need to. But that may be more trouble than you want.

Comment: No that's fine.  Just seemed like the proper way was to use update-grub